# How do you rearrange a date (09-09-2013) to (2013-09-09) with php?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure this out, I am not the php developer, but I was tasked with this anyways. So, I have been trying to figure it out. I have been asked to replace the - with commas, and rearrange the dates. For example `mm-dd-yyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`

This is how I replace the -

```
$TheDate = "09-09-2013";
$TheDate = str_replace('-', ',', $TheDate);
echo $TheDate;
```

Now, the problem is that I don't even know where to start on how to rearrange the numbers. Could someone please lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('09-09-2013'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use php `date()` and `strtotime()` to do this. It's the slandered way.

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('09-09-2013'));
```

Output:- https://eval.in/807312

Reference:- [PHP date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: thanks  Divern.Glad to help you. :):)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way to do it, you should use date/time classes but here goes anyway:

```
$dateArray = explode('-', $TheDate);
$myDate = $dateArray[2] . '-' . $dateArray[0] . '-' . $dateArray[1];
```

You shouldn't do it this way though because it's not flexible to the user locale or lots of other things that could go wrong.